# subdirectory htaccess url rewrites

Tags: htaccess, apache

I have a project with this skimmed structure:

```
-proj
-----pages
---------example
-------------pages
-------------.htaccess
---------.htaccess
```

I managed to get it working so that all url's go to /pages from the get-go using my project root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rewrite /pages/area/index.php url -> /area/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)
RewriteRule !\.[a-z0-4]{2,4}$ /pages/%1index.php [NC,L]

# remaining req's get rewritten to /pages/ -> now we don't need index.php in tree root
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/$1 [L]
```

This code was taken from an answer elsewhere and as I'm no htaccess guru, I thought I could use it in my subdirectory .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rewrite /pages/area/index.php url -> /area/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)
RewriteRule example/pages/\.[a-z0-4]{2,4}/$ /example/pages/%1index.php [NC,L]

# remaining req's get rewritten to /pages/ -> now we don't need index.php in tree root
RewriteRule ^example/(.*) /example/pages/$1 [L]
```

But going to `/example/pages/` in my browser shows the `index.php` instead of 404'ing as it should be trying to look for a folder called `pages` within the `pages` directory - but it seems no.

I could try and add this all to the project root .htaccess and it would be a lot simpler to achieve - however, I'm aiming for my project design to be modular, so these `example` area's can be added/removed whenever.

How do I rewrite `http://localhost/area/pages/` into `http://localhost/area/` using the .htaccess file in the subdirectories under the top-level `pages` directory?

Comment: I assume `/proj` must be your document root? Is `/area` the equivalent of `example` in your "skimmed structure"? "But going to `/example/pages/` in my browser shows the `index.php`" - Yes, your root `.htaccess` file rewrites the request to `/pages/example/pages/index.php` and the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory does nothing since this file exists. I'm struggling to understand why (you think) a request for `/example/pages` should "look for a folder called `pages` within the `pages` directory"? Are `pages` and `pages` actually two different strings like `pages` and `foo`?

Comment: "How do I rewrite `http://localhost/area/pages/` into `http://localhost/area/` using the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectories under the top-level `pages` directory?" - That doesn't seem to make sense from the information given? Do you have a functioning website in the root, as well as in the named subdirectories? What is the URL structure you are striving for? And where are these URLs intended to be routed to? Are you routing everything to `index.php`?

Comment: Ah... "it should be trying to look for a folder called `pages` within the `pages` directory" - you are expecting the last rule in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file to "win". No, it doesn't work like that. "I'm aiming for my project design to be modular, so these example area's can be added/removed whenever." - then shouldn't the "subdirectory" `.htaccess` file be inside the `example` directory, not outside of it?

Comment: (Sorry, too many queries...!)

Comment: @MrWhite hey :) indeed, proj = document root, example = area :) and oh sorry ,the .htaccess is inside the example folder! My bad, I can see how that can be misconstrued lemme amend

Comment: @MrWhite essentially, I have a project that currently routes everything to the `/pages` directory. However, I'd like a pages subdirectory inside each area for, well their other pages. But I don't want pages in the area url, so I'd like `http://localhost/area/somethingelse.php` instead of `http://localhost/area/pages/somethingelse.php`

Comment: From your diagram, you seem to have moved your root `.htaccess` file into the `/pages` directory - I assume that is a "typo"?

Comment: How does `index.php` fit into this? In your directives (in both the root and subdirectory `.htaccess` files) you are rewriting to this? But you have another directive that doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `.htaccess` file in the document root in order to rewrite a request of the form `/area/somethingelse.php` to the `/pages` subdirectory in the root (ie. `/pages/area/somethingelse.php`) before the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory (ie. `/pages/area/.htaccess`) is able to rewrite the request a second time to `/pages/area/pages/somethingelse.php` - the eventual target.

> I have a project that currently routes everything to the `/pages` directory.

However, if this is an entirely separate "project" then you have to be careful of conflicts. Your directives are also rewriting to an `index.php` file - but you make no reference to this in your question? For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to ignore that for now(!) and simply rewrite to the `/pages` (and `/pages/example/pages`) subdirectories.

Try something like the following instead:

`/.htaccess` (file in the document root)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Do not process rewritten requests OR requests that map to existing files
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite EVERYTHING to the /pages subdirectory
RewriteRule ^ /pages%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

`/pages/example/.htaccess` (file in the subdirectory)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Do not process requests that map to existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite EVERYTHING to the "pages" sub-subdirectory if not already
# eg. /pages/example/foo.php to /pages/example/pages/foo.php  
RewriteRule ^(?!pages/)(.*) pages/$1 [L]
```

`(?!pages/)` is a negative lookahead to avoid rewriting requests that are already for the `/pages` sub-subdirectory (inside the `/pages/example` directory).

> But going to `/example/pages/` in my browser shows the `index.php` instead of 404'ing as it should be trying to look for a folder called pages within the pages directory - but it seems no.

A request for `/example/pages/` will now result in a 403 Forbidden as it will attempt to list the directory contents `/pages/example/pages/`. This is assuming `Options -Indexes` is set and you have no `index.php` file located at `/pages/example/pages/index.php`.

Comment: you kids and your htaccess wizardry haha thank you, works perfectly :)